# Event when web component has loaded

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have a web component like this

```
<template id="component">
    <link href="/static/css/main.cacbacc7.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <span id="react-app"></span>
</template>

<script>
  (function (window, document) {
    const doc = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript).ownerDocument;
    const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      attachedCallback: {
        value: function () {
          const template = doc.querySelector('template#component').content;
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
          shadowRoot.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
          // executeThis() when all scripts have been loaded
        }
      },
    });
    document.registerElement('react-webcomponent', { prototype: proto });
  })(window, document);
</script>
```

Can I know when all `script` tags in my `template` have been loaded?

**Update**

What I am currently doing is

```
const scripts = [...shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('script')];
let scriptsLoaded = 0;
scripts.forEach(function (script) {
  script.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (++scriptsLoaded >= scripts.length) {
      LoadReactAppIntoShadowDomContainer(shadowRoot.querySelector('#react-app'));
    }
  })
});
```

But I am hoping for a nicer way.

About the possible duplicate: Will it work for web components?

Comment: You can do that very easily if you are using JQuery.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to load jQuery just for this little thing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: Might be, but will it work for web components?

Comment: Is your goal, `to know when your components have completed parsing upgrading and loading`?

Comment: My goal is to know when the scripts have loaded because I want to call a function that is defined in the scripts

Comment: why can't you use `WebcomponentsReady` ?

Comment: Also, Just because, the script tags are inside the component, doesn't mean they are scoped. they are still globally available

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't `WebcomponentsReady ` a polyfill of Polymer only?

Comment: As for the scripts being global, how does that make a difference?

Comment: Using the load event (or onload event handler, or the onload element attribute) on script is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, as of now,

- you do not have event listeners for `onload` of the dom in your shadow root
- when you define a custom element, you can have a `connectedCallback` which is called when you attach an element to your DOM

from what you are trying, it seems to me, that you are trying to ascertain, the exact time when your shadow DOM loads its internal scripts

from what I know, scripts are not scoped to your element, and are global.

So Instead of trying to do what you are doing at the moment which is,

- querying the shadow Root's DOM structure, collecting the script tags and attaching an onload,

you can simply slap an onload to the tags which work like they always have.

Further, you might be interested in `mutation observers` if you may want to observe for changes to your shadow DOM, once it is `attached` and beyond.

AFAIK, you can not observe DOM changes while you are constructing your element itself / before it is attached

Or, if you are defining your elements in a different file and prefer using `HTML Imports` to import them onto the document,

you can use the `webcomponentsready` listener from the document that imports, which fires when all the DOM is imported, parsed, and loaded

If there is indeed a way to observe the DOM or listen to template attachments to your element, I would also like to know.

Also, Since you are trying to embed your react app into the custom element, which is probably why you had this question of knowing when to call the `loadreactapp` function, you may want to consider using `slots` in your shadow DOM, which open up places where you may distribute content after your element has been registered on the browser

Just add your apps or other custom elements, by passing in the attribute `slot=<slotname>`

Comment: I've absolutely no idea why this is the accepted answer, as it doesn't actually answer the the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

Your update example is the best way I know of.

I had a similar issue looking to prevent FOUC on my components that were importing CSS via  tags.

The only solution I could find is as per your update.  QS the ShadowRoot to find the `<link>` or `<scripts>`, add a load event listener to each and compare the load count.

The one optimisation you might consider, is when the count matches you can dispatch your own custom load event from the shadow root itself, that a listener on your component shadow root (or further up the tree) can handle.

```
var event = new CustomEvent('load');
shadowRoot.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If you want it to bubble up and cross the shadow boundary you'll need to add `composed : true` to the event args.

```
var event = new CustomEvent('load', {bubbles : true, composed : true});
shadowRoot.dispatchEvent(event);
```